# Meteor(Blaze)[1.6] - [TypeError: Buffer.alloc is not a function] Unable to load plugin meteor

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-deployment, meteor-blaze

I am trying to deploy meteor-app on AMAZON-SERVER. Unable to get success while running MUP STOP.

I created exactly **/client/lib/init.js**, wrote 
**require("buffer").Buffer**  //not working

**var Buffer = require('buffer/').Buffer** //not working

Also tried,
**global.Buffer = function() {}**
**global.Buffer.isBuffer = () => false**  //not working

And
**meteor npm update** @production // not working

Still getting the same error.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE** project's node version to latest at server and there will be no error.